# How to send a local image instead of URL to Computer Vision API using React

Tags: reactjs, azure, file-upload, computer-vision, ocr

I would like to upload local image file and extract text from it. I followed the below link and it works as expected when I pass URL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/static-web-app/add-computer-vision-react-app

I managed to configure for local image and get the base64 encoded dataURL of the uploaded image. But when I pass base64 encoded dataURL to Computer Vision API , it says "Input data is not a valid image" (POST 400 status code). I am getting error in the line that is shown below:
const analysis = await computerVisionClient.analyzeImage(urlToAnalyze, { visualFeatures });

The code I have included for handling local image:

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function()
    {
        setFileSelected(reader.result) // this is the base64 encoded dataurl
    }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

In computerVision.js file, I have changed the 'contentType' in header as below.

```
 const computerVisionClient = new ComputerVisionClient(
    new ApiKeyCredentials({ inHeader: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} }), endpoint);
```

I tried replacing client.read() with readTextInStream() as per docs in computerVision.js (please refer above link), but still throws error.

May I know why I get the error "Input data is not a valid image" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/overview#image-requirements) for input requirements.

There is a brand new online portal provided by Microsoft https://preview.vision.azure.com/demo/OCR

The advantage is that it will directly list your available resources so you just have to pick the right one, then you test, and there are also some samples.